# Drawing Parameter space figure - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, pde

I'm solving a system of non-linear diffusion partial differential equations using **pdepe** in MATLAB. In this model, basically I'm changing only two parameters, say P1 and P2. P1 varies from 1-100 and P2 varies from 5-50000. Since I have four pde's in my system, I'm getting four answers; say A1,A2,A3 and A4.

There are 500 subdivisions for x and 101  subdivisions for t. Therefore, the answers that I get for A1,A2,A3 and A4 are all matrices with dimension 101x500.

Now, I need to draw a 2-D figure(known as parameter space figure) that describes the solution A2 w.r.t P1 and P2. That is, in the figure,my x-axis will be P1 and my y-axix will be P2. Could you please help me in coding this in MATLAB?

Thank you!

Comment: What of all that are you stuck with? `surf(p1,p2,a2)` will work

Comment: Thanks Ander! That's a great help.

Comment: Hello Ander, I tried on that.but I got an error message "Data dimension must agree ". My P1 and P2 are just scalars and A2 is a matrix.

Comment: We need a [mcve] !

Comment: Hello Ander! Here's the explanation of the parameter space figure that I need...For lots of different values of P1 and P2 we can do the full simulation. We do this for large enough final time so that the solution goes to steady state.Then at the final time where we have the solution, we can store the average value of the solution of A2 (eg numerically integrate the A2 density over the space and divide by length of the space).  
That way we have a scalar quantity at each value of P1 and P2 and we can summarize as a surface plot. Hope this makes sense! I use pdepe for the simulation.

Comment: Then surf will work

Comment: what is the command for numerical integration in pdepe? Will pdeval work?

Comment: That is a question that has nothing to do with the original one. You are asking how to plot.

Comment: yes Ander.. Coul you please explain me the matlab code for this process? I need to store the average value of the solution of A2 (after numerically integrating the A2 density over the space and divide by length of the space).

Comment: Oh, wait, so you don't have any of all that you are asking about? We are not a code writting service my friend. you need to try stuff and show us what you tried. "How do I solve my engineering problem" is off-topic in stackoverflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126076/discussion-between-ccc-and-ander-biguri).